# Geometry of a diagonal in a flag

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, puzzle

### Problem

I came across the [flag of Trinidad and Tobago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Trinidad_and_Tobago) and it got me thinking about the geometry of that diagonal. Picture below.

[image: Flag of Trinidad and Tobago]

If you look at the diagonal, you'll see it doesn't just go from one corner to the opposite. It's placed in such a way that the lower border of the stripe touches one corner, and the upper border touches the opposite corner.

I found a few other flags with diagonals placed in that way, like the flags of [Brunei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Brunei), [Republic of Congo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Republic_of_the_Congo), or the [Democratic Republic of Congo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo).

I was thinking, how would you draw that diagonal if you only knew the flag's width and height, and the stripe width. I haven't found an easy way to solve this, and I was wondering if someone has thought about this before, or wanted to give it a try.

I've also read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50572/calculate-measurements-for-a-diagonal-fence-beam) before posting this question, thanks to a recommendation from "similar questions". That one is actually the same setup, but the questions asked are different, so I'm still unsure how to solve this problem.

### What I've done so far

I'll start with some definitions. The dimensions I've defined can be found on the figure below.

[image: Flag diagram with the dimensions I've defined]

The bottom-left corner detail with more dimensions below:

[image: A detail of the diagram above, with more dimensions defined]

- Flag's width: $w$.
- Flag's height: $h$.
- Flag's diagonal: $d$. Note this is also the stripe's diagonal.
- Stripe's width, or "thickness": $t$.
- Stripe's length: $l$. Note this is the distance $\overline{AD}$, or $\overline{BC}$.
- The angle between the stripe and the bottom border of the flag: $\alpha$.
- Vertical distance $\overline{AB}$: $y$.
- Horizontal distance $\overline{AB}$: $x$.

I ultimately want to know how to define $x$ and $y$ in terms of $w$, $h$, and $t$. i.e. $x(w, h, t)$ and $y(w, h, t)$.

One thought that I have in mind, but haven't been able to write mathematically is the relation between the thickness and the angle. It should be clear that:
$$
\begin{align*}
t &= 0 \to \alpha = \arctan(h / w), &B \equiv A\\
t &= w \to \alpha = \pi/2, &B \equiv G
\end{align*}
$$

The relations I've found:
$$
\begin{align}
t^2 + l^2 = d^2 \tag{1} \\
w^2 + h^2 = d^2 \tag{2} \\
x^2 + y^2 = t^2 \tag{3} \\
l \cos{\alpha} = w - x \tag{4} \\
l \sin{\alpha} = h + y \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ come from applying the Pythagoras theorem to the triangles $\triangle{ABC}$, $\triangle{AGC}$, and $\triangle{AJB}$, respectively. Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ come from defining the flag's width and height using the stripe dimensions.

With them, I've done the following steps:

1. $(4)^2 + (5)^2$, to remove the $\sin$ and $\cos$, arriving to:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   x^2 - 2wx + y^2 + 2hy + w^2 + h^2 - l^2 = 0 \tag{6} \\
   \end{align}
   $$
2. Rewrite $(1)$ as $l^2 = d^2 - t^2$, and substitute the value of $d$ from $(2)$, and the value of $t$ from $(3)$, arriving to:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   l^2 = w^2 + h^2 - x^2 - y^2 \tag{7} \\
   \end{align}
   $$
3. Substitute $(7)$ in $(6)$, arriving to:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   x^2 - wx + y^2 + hy = 0 \tag{8} \\
   \end{align}
   $$

So far this looks good to me, but I'm not sure how to get to $x(w, h, t)$ and $y(w, h, t)$. I can do $x(y)$ as:
$$
\begin{align}
x = \frac{w\pm\sqrt{w^2-4(y^2 + hy)}}{2} \tag{9} \\
\end{align}
$$

And from here I could substitute that value of $x$ in $(3)$, but I haven't found a way to isolate $y$ and reach $y(w, h, t)$.

### Questions

1. Am I heading in the right direction?
2. Have I missed some relation that would make this simpler?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379007/help-calculating-angles-for-woodworking/4097895#4097895)

Comment: Thanks for the link @JaapScherphuis! Very useful. I think I'll be able to solve it with that info. I didn't take into account how the length $\overline{AE}$ relates with $w$, $h$, and $t$. That could be just the one I mentioned I didn't know how to write mathematically, between the angel and the thickness.